# How to show .doc file in web browser?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, iframe, ms-office

I want to show all type of files in my web browser. The problem is that I am able to view all type of contents except MSOffice (.doc, xls, pptx).
I am using SPRING MVC and the data is coming to jsp using `model.addAttribute()`
Here is the code:

```
<iframe src="${url}" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
```

Here, ${url} is coming from

model.addAttribute("url","url");

Which is inside the controller part.
The problem is that , everything except office files (.doc.. etc), I am able to view or read, but when I click on the .doc file , it just downloaded and does not view in the browser. Although, I have checked, in this case also, the data is coming from controller. Help me.

Comment: This is not a matter of your web-app, it is all about what file-types the brwoser supports. And most just don't act as an MS-office-viewer.

Comment: But I have to show doc in web browser, so is there any other method for achieving it.

Comment: The only solution: render it server-side to html or some image-format and send this to the client. Quite some task...